# getting id from datalist

Tags: javascript, html, input, datalist

I need help because I need to convert it:

```
<select name="productId">
       <option value=""></option>
       <c:forEach items="${productsBeanId.activeProductsList}" var="product">                    
                <option value="${product.productId}">${product.productName}</option>
       </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

On it:

```
<input list="productId">
      <datalist id="productId">
          <c:forEach items="${productsBeanId.activeProductsList}" var="product">                    
              <option value="${product.productId}">${product.productName}</option>
          </c:forEach>                  
      </datalist>
```

And I need to get the productId to work with it on the database, creating a product.

The line `<option value="${product.productId}">${product.productName}</option>` is the problematic one to me, because I need to save the productId, but to show the productName on the list, to make easier findings.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var selectObj = document.getElementById( "productId" );
var innerHTMLSelect = selectObj.innerHTML; //first save the innerHTML of select 
var selectParent = selectObj.parentNode();
selectParent.removeNode(selectObj); //remove current select element

selectParent += '<input list="productId"><datalist id="productId"></datalist>'; //append the data list to the parent
document.getElementById( "productId" ).innerHTML = innerHTMLSelect ; //put the saved innerHTML to the current data list element
```

Comment: Hello:
This way is not correct to me, because with this sollution you're mixing concepts.

Comment: @FranGV Didn't get you. is this not converting to your desired output?

Comment: No, I solved it getting the desired product by name from the database, but id is better to get the entire product. At moment it is solved by this way.